# How would I create a "glowing" image like this in Gimp/Photoshop?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, gimp, image-editing

I recently saw the below wallpaper, which appears to have been created from this base image:

[image]

(Apparently the wallpaper is "glowing", like a fast-moving neon light).

[image]

I have some cartoony drawings which I would like to convert to a similar format. I have access to Photoshop if there is a filter out there that would do it, or Gimp, ImageMagick, Paint.net, etc if there are some basic steps I could follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extract contours by colour or intensity (see [how-to select by histogram range](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4839/gimp-select-by-histogram-range)). Invert them and [add some glow](http://gimp-tutorials.net/gimp-glow-effect). You can use motion blur or smudge tool to make it appear more dynamic. Put the glowing light above the original, add dark background, experiment with blending modes.